# SQL Server and sqsh Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqsh

I'm using sqsh to execute a stored procedure:

I simplified the procedure like this to be easyer for you to read:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
    
AS
BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM Keys
            WHERE 1=1
            ;WITH CTE AS
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM MyTableName
                ORDER BY CreationTime ASC
            )
            SELECT *
            FROM CTE
END
;
go
```

The error I get is this:

```
Use: \go [-d display] [-h] [-f] [-n] [-p] [-m mode] [-s sec]
          [-t [filter]] [-w width] [-x [xgeom]] [-T title] [xacts]
     -d display  When used with -x, send result to named display
     -h          Suppress headers
     -f          Suppress footers
     -n          Do not expand variables
     -p          Report runtime statistics
     -m mode     Switch display mode for result set
     -s sec      Sleep sec seconds between transactions
     -t [filter] Filter SQL through program
                 Optional filter value overrides default variable $filter_prog
     -w width    Override value of $width
     -x [xgeom]  Send result set to a XWin output window
                 Optional xgeom value overrides default variable $xgeom
     -T title    Used in conjunction with -x to set window title
     xacts       Repeat batch xacts times
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1
Server 'myServer', Procedure 'MyProc', Line xx
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
```

---

This is the not semplified version:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyCustomProcedure]
    @BatchSize INT  WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
            DECLARE @CurrentName varchar(max)
            SET @CurrentName = [dbo].[GetCurrentyName]()
            DECLARE @CurrentID INT
            SELECT @CurrentID=ID FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE OriginalName = @CurrentName

            ;WITH CTE AS
            (
                SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) *
                FROM [dbo].[SerialNumbers]
                WHERE ID <> @CurrentID
                ORDER BY CreationTime ASC
            )
            UPDATE CTE
                SET EncodedSerial = (Encode(Key_GUID(@CurrentName), CONVERT(VARCHAR,(Decode(EncodedSerial))))),
                ID=@CurrentID
END
;

go
```

I've already looked at other similar questions.
I can't find anything wrong with the syntax, what else could it be? SQLServer version?

Comment: Is your actual table name (`MyTable`) a SQL Server reserved word?  Similarly, do you get the error if you run the procedure directly in SQL Server?

Comment: No, `MyTable` is not the actual table name. I changed it for clarity
Unfortunately right now I can't try it directly in SQL Server

Comment: You have simplified this so much you have removed the error. What you posted works perfectly fine. Perhaps you should share the actual code?

Comment: I think we'd need to see your actual code. Change the names, but leave the structure. This query seems to have been extremely simplified, and it's not really doing anything.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the `;` between `END` and `GO`.

Comment: I've added the code with changed names

Comment: @LukStorms , what do you mean?

Comment: Just copy & paste the select in SSMS, replace variables, run it and see if it fails?

Comment: I can't use SSMS right now, I can only use sqsh

Comment: I don't think the error is there because replacing it with a `select * from CTE` I still get the same error

Comment: The error could be in the code of `[dbo].[GetCurrentyName]`.

Comment: Is GetCurrentyName the correct name? Or a typo.

Comment: You can't have an `ORDER BY` in the CTE. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and a subselect to get the number you need.

Comment: Anyway, I found the update of the CTE odd at first. But that trick works after all. [simple test here](http://rextester.com/WZFG92568)

Comment: @LukStorms Updating a CTE is an easy way to make sure you're updating only a specific set of records. It's a pretty cool trick. :-)

Comment: I was wrong about the `ORDER BY` when used with `TOP x`. But the error still seems to indicate the problem was around the `ORDER BY`. Is there any chance that your `SELECT FROM keys` can return `NULL`? Try changing it to `SELECT @CurrentID=COALESCE(ID,0) FROM .....`. Also, you may get unexpected results if you just use `CONVERT(VARCHAR,x)` without specifying a length. Go with `CONVERT(VARCHAR(nnnnn),x)` instead.

Comment: `decode()` ???  Are you sure you are using SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is quite old, but in case anyone finds this in the future here is the solution.

`sqsh` uses the command `\go` to break batches up.  `sqsh` also uses the semi-colon itself as a "keyword" as a sort of in-line `\go` command.  So essentially, your procedure is split into 2 non-sense batches:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyCustomProcedure]
    @BatchSize INT  WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
            DECLARE @CurrentName varchar(max)
            SET @CurrentName = [dbo].[GetCurrentyName]()
            DECLARE @CurrentID INT
            SELECT @CurrentID=ID FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE OriginalName = @CurrentName
```

and

```
WITH CTE AS
            (
                SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) *
                FROM [dbo].[SerialNumbers]
                WHERE ID <> @CurrentID
                ORDER BY CreationTime ASC
            )
            UPDATE CTE
                SET EncodedSerial = (Encode(Key_GUID(@CurrentName), CONVERT(VARCHAR,(Decode(EncodedSerial))))),
                ID=@CurrentID
END
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server is going to complain if you remove the semi-colon, so you need to disable the semi-colon batch separation function.

From the man page:

```
semicolon_hack (boolean)
           Toggles on the ability to use a ';' as an in-line command terminator. This feature is
           not recommended and is only in here because enough users complained.  See section
           COMMANDS, In-Line Go.
```

This is a variable you can either set from the `sqsh` shell or from the original sqsh command via the `-L` option to set variable: `-Lsemicolon_hack=false`.

You actually have a second error there complaining about the usage of `GO`.  `sqsh` will throw an error if you use `GO`.  You will need to submit the batch either way or sqsh will literally do nothing, so change that `GO` to `\go`.  So the final sql file should look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyCustomProcedure]
    @BatchSize INT  WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
            DECLARE @CurrentName varchar(max)
            SET @CurrentName = [dbo].[GetCurrentyName]()
            DECLARE @CurrentID INT
            SELECT @CurrentID=ID FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE OriginalName = @CurrentName

            ;WITH CTE AS
            (
                SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) *
                FROM [dbo].[SerialNumbers]
                WHERE ID <> @CurrentID
                ORDER BY CreationTime ASC
            )
            UPDATE CTE
                SET EncodedSerial = (Encode(Key_GUID(@CurrentName), CONVERT(VARCHAR,(Decode(EncodedSerial))))),
                ID=@CurrentID
END

\go
```

Note: You already did this, but the `\go` command must always be preceded by a new line.